# Could you tell me what's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, fibonacci

When I call my fib function it doesn't return anything. Can you tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong?

```
def fib(n, List = []):
    if n > 0:
        if len(List) == 0 or len(List) == 1:
            List.append(1)
        else:
            List.append(List[len(List) - 2] + List[len(List) - 1])
        fib(n - 1, List)
    else:
        return List

l = fib(5)
print(l)  # >> None
```

Comment: Your `if` clause does not contain a `return` statement.

Comment: @khelwood, is right you need to change it to `return fib(n - 1, List)`

Comment: Consider renaming the title of your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `fib(n - 1, List)` to `return fib(n - 1, List)`:

```
def fib(n, List = []):
    if n > 0:
        if len(List) == 0 or len(List) == 1:
            List.append(1)
        else:
            List.append(List[len(List) - 2] + List[len(List) - 1])
        return fib(n - 1, List)
    else:
        return List
```